# Transferring call from GSM modem to PC

Tags: gsm

I have the following scenario.

I have a LAN and more than one GSM modems are connected to a server. I want to receive incoming call on GSM modem and transfer this call to other PC on the network. Is it possible? Can anyone give me an idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'transfer the call'.

You will have to receive the calls from each modem on the server only, then you can implement something like a VOIP/sound streaming system by which you can simply send and receive the audio between server and client(s).